# In RazorSQL, is there an automatic way of seeing how many rows of data were returned by a query?

Tags: razorsql

I am new to RazorSQL, so excuse my ignorance. My version of RazorSQL (v. 10.4.4 64-bit) is connected to a SQLite database on a MAC. When I execute a query, there doesn't seem to be an easy and automatic way of seeing how many rows of data were returned by the query. Obviously, I can try to scroll down my results table in the preview window, but if the table is huge, it becomes impractical.